# Search speed improvement in one of the columns depending on the value of another column using numpy & python 3

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am looking for a more efficient way in terms of speed since the number of data is considerably higher than in this example (it is a simple and shortened example) and I need to use numpy arrays and masks. I am aware that I have put a solution but as I say it is extremely slow for the needs.

Thanks in advance

```
import numpy as np

# [name, age, US_Cities_Zip_Codes]
database = np.array([
    ['Sophia', 45, 35801],
    ['Jacob', 76, 72201],
    ['Mason', 31, 20001],
    ['Isabella', 57, 35801],
    ['William', 24, 33124],
    ['Emma', 37, 33124],
    ['Olivia', 76, 35801],
    ['Jayden', 29, 35801],
    ['Chloe', 64, 55801],
    ['Ryan', 30, 72201],
    ['Joshua', 45, 20001],
    ['Owen', 27, 55801],
    ['Alyssa', 75, 35801],
    ['Kaylee', 32, 33124],
    ['Arianna', 45, 55801]
])

zip_codes = np.unique(database[:, 2])
# zip_codes = ['20001' '33124' '35801' '55801' '72201']

older_ages_by_zip = []
younger_ages_by_zip = []
dif_ages_by_zip = []

# # # Start of the part of the code that needs to be improved 
for us_zip in zip_codes:
    us_zip_mask = (database[:, 2] == us_zip)  # I want to keep this mask here for other reasons
    us_zip_ages = database[us_zip_mask, 1].astype('float')  # I want to keep this as float for other reasons
    # for: 20001 -> [45., 31.] (In this particular case there are only 2 values, but in others there will be hundreds)

    older_age = np.max(us_zip_ages)
    younger_age = np.min(us_zip_ages)

    older_ages_by_zip.append(older_age)
    younger_ages_by_zip.append(younger_age)
    dif_ages_by_zip.append(older_age - younger_age)

    # # # # # # # # # # #
    # Other stuffs here #
    # # # # # # # # # # #
# # # End of the part of the code that needs to be improved 

print(zip_codes)
print(older_ages_by_zip)
print(younger_ages_by_zip)
print(dif_ages_by_zip)

# ['20001' '33124' '35801' '55801' '72201']
# [45.0, 37.0, 76.0, 64.0, 76.0]
# [31.0, 24.0, 29.0, 27.0, 30.0]
# [14.0, 13.0, 47.0, 37.0, 46.0]
```

### EDIT:

Let's assume that after some operations I have this new database:

```
database = database[:, 1:]  # Of FLOAT values (I know that this are int but let's assume they are floats
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your database has several columns with different types of data (strings, ints, floats), numpy isn't the most efficient tool to use.

Use the pandas library to store your data in a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.Dataframe(database, columns=['name', 'age', 'US_Cities_Zip_Codes']
```

You can then create masks easily:

```
mask = df['US_Cities_Zip_Codes'] == us_zip

# getting your filtered data
df[mask]
```

You can use the apply() function to create a new column with the age as a float.
You can also carry out your min and max operations with the existing functions in the pandas library

Comment: Thx you a lot @Avandale!! I saw that pandas it's a great tool but as I also saw, numpy it's more efficient so lets assume the edited case in my initial question

Comment: pandas is built on top of numpy, so it's extremely efficient as well. For what you are trying to do, it will be more efficient than numpy because the equivalent numpy code is very complex